# How can you use os.chdir to go to a path minus the last step of it?

Tags: python, operating-system

For example, a method is passed a path as a parameter, this path might be "C:/a/b/c/d", what if I want to use os.chdir() to change to C:/a/b/c (without the last folder)?  Can os.chdir() take the ".." command?

Comment: "Try it out" is not the most reliable approach if you want to be flexible across platforms.

Comment: Although depending on symlinks, going to d and then up a level may not work out the same as going to c.

Comment: hair, note that “..” is not a command; in all POSIX-conformant operating systems and their filesystems (yes, that includes MS Windows) and then some, all directories have a valid entry named “..” (although there is special code to cater for the fact that a `chdir` from `/a/b/c` to `..` results in `/a/b` as the *current working directory*, not `/a/b/c/..`, even if the latter is valid).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`os.chdir()` can take `'..'` as argument, yes. However, Python provides a platform-agnostic way: by using `os.pardir`:

```
os.chdir(os.pardir)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`os.path.dirname`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname):

```
In [1]: import os.path

In [2]: os.path.dirname('C:/a/b/c/d')
Out[2]: 'C:/a/b/c'
```

**edit**: It's been pointed out that this doesn't remove the last component if the path ends with a slash. As a more robust alternative, I propose the following:

```
In [5]: os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:/a/b/c/d', '..'))
Out[5]: 'C:/a/b/c'

In [6]: os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:/a/b/c/d/', '..'))
Out[6]: 'C:/a/b/c'
```

The `'..'` can be replaced with `os.path.pardir` to make the code even more portable (at least theoretically).

Comment: as Sven pointed out when I answered this: This method fails if there is a trailing slash. `os.path.dirname("/a/b/c/") == "/a/b/c"`.

Answer (score 2):

The [os.path module](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) has some functions that are useful for this sort of thing.

`os.path.normpath()` can be used to convert a path containing references like `..` to an absolute path. This would ensure consistent behaviour regardless of how the operating system handles paths.

`os.chdir(os.path.normpath("C:/a/b/c/.."))` should accomplish what you want.

Comment: Be careful with trailing slashes or back slashes.

Comment: Eek. I noticed that when testing. Changed to a solution that works.

Comment: os.path.normpath(os.getcwd() + os.sep + os.pardir)
Will get you back one